# MySQL view from three tables

Tags: mysql, view, many-to-many

I've read bunches of posts, books, watched videos, etc. etc. but SQL JOINS just have never made any sense to me... =/

So here's the deal...

Three tables:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `feature` (  
  `feature_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,  
  `title` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,  
  `description` TEXT NOT NULL ,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`feature_id`) )  
ENGINE = InnoDB;  

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `requirement` (  
  `requirement_id` INT NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT ,  
  `title` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL ,  
  `description` TEXT NOT NULL ,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`requirement_id`) ,  
  UNIQUE INDEX `title_UNIQUE` (`title` ASC) )  
ENGINE = InnoDB;  

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `feature_requirement` (  
  `fk_feature_id` INT NOT NULL ,  
  `fk_requirement_id` INT NOT NULL ,  
  PRIMARY KEY (`fk_feature_id`, `fk_requirement_id`) ,  
  INDEX `fk_feature_requirement_requirement1` (`fk_requirement_id` ASC) ,  
  INDEX `fk_feature_requirement_feature1` (`fk_feature_id` ASC) )  
ENGINE = InnoDB;
```

Some features may have multiple requirements and some features will have the same requirements (that is, the same requirement applies to multiple features) Hence, the third table for a many-to-may relationship.

I want to be able to select all the requirements for a particular feature (by feature_id) and I'm trying to make this into a VIEW.

After a lot of error messages about "unknown columns" and "non unique aliases;" I finally got this one to work:

```
CREATE VIEW `project_feature_requirement` AS  
SELECT r.*  
FROM `requirement` `r`  
INNER JOIN `feature_requirement` `fr`  
    on `r`.`requirement_id` = `fr`.`fk_requirement_id`  
INNER JOIN `feature` `f`  
    on `fr`.`fk_feature_id` = `f`.`feature_id`
```

However, that only gives me requirement_id, title, & description to SELECT from though.
...which is useless

I have four other VIEWs to create that will be the same type of query.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Are there any free programs that will query my schema and run me through a "wizard" or something to specify which tables/columns I want and what column(s) I want to select on and build the query for me???  Maybe I could finally figure it out if could play with a utility like that.

Thanks again!
Todd

Comment: You say "requirement_id, title, & description" is useless, well, what do you want then? You only selected the items out of the requirement table.

Comment: Try to put this all into a [SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com) and people are more likely to try to help

Comment: Let me try to (perhaps over)simplify what a JOIN does. If it makes it any easier to understand what a join does, picture a Venn Diagram. Your two tables are the two circles, and when you do an inner join, you are grabbing the "stuff" that is in the overlapping part of the circles. A left join grabs all the "stuff" in the left circle, plus whatever "stuff" in the right circle matches up.

Comment: @Poodlehat - That's what I mean "it's useless" the VIEW I created was just an overly complicated query that is the same as just querying the requirements table.  I want to be able to get all the requirements by feature_id (but that's not available in the view.

Comment: @Jason - I'll have to check that out.  Looks cool.

Comment: @Poodlehat again =) - Thanks for that description.  It is useful for understanding what elements get included in a JOIN.  Thanks! =)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work for you, but you should work on your naming conventions within the database. Having multiple fields named title in the same query can get unnecessarily confusing:

```
CREATE VIEW `project_feature_requirement` AS  
    SELECT r.*, f.feature_id, f.title as ftitle, f.description as fdesc  
    FROM `requirement` `r`  
    INNER JOIN `feature_requirement` `fr`  
        on `r`.`requirement_id` = `fr`.`fk_requirement_id`  
    INNER JOIN `feature` `f`  
        on `fr`.`fk_feature_id` = `f`.`feature_id`
```

This may be a clearer and less error-prone way of writing the query:

```
SELECT r.*, f.feature_id, f.title as ftitle, f.description as fdesc  
FROM feature_requirement fr 
JOIN requirement r ON r.requirement_id=fr.fk_requirement_id
JOIN feature f on f.feature_id=fr.fk_feature_id
```

Comment: Thanks Orbiting Eden.  Worked like a charm and the reading the second version helped a lot.  I realized that, kind of "reading from the bottom up," I combine my tables and provide the aliases for the data tables, then the relational table, and finally use those aliases to specify the desired columns.
I typically use fully qualified names, so I didn't think of the name collisions as a problem. This is my first effort to use VIEWs, and I see what you mean about the names creating an additional problem when defining views.
Thanks! =)